# Basic solve with symbolic variable returns said variable

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I cannot get the very basic symbolic expressions to solve in Matlab. I have the symbolic toolbox installed (checked with ver).

Code:

```
syms x
xsol = solve(10*x == 1, x)
```

The expected solution would simply be x=1/10. Somehow Matlab returns just x, so basically it doesn't solve at all. I tried multiple examples from the help documents and I haven't progressed. I am thinking there might be something wrong with my symbolic toolbox installation?

If anyone has an idea what I could do wrong, please let me know!

edit: I'm using Matlab 2014a by the way

Comment: That's weird it works fine for me. What if you use solve('10*x = 1,x')

Comment: Thanks! So I know it is my installation. I don't run into errors while using syms, though. Any way to check if the toolbox is working?

Comment: Not that I know of. What if you try solve('10*x = 1,x') ?

Comment: ans = 1/10, seems to work fine without any symbolic variables indeed.

Comment: Interesting! It might have to be with the version you are using, but I don't know much about this sorry!

Comment: you could type `which syms` to find out what the path for your symbolic toolbox installation is. I use 2014a as well, for me the path is `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\syms.m`. It might be possible that you downloaded a custom toolbox that overrides this path, for example the optimization toolbox Mosek comes with its own version of `quadprog`.

Comment: What version of the Symbolic Math toolbox are you using (`ver symbolic`)? It should show (2014a) in parentheses next to the version number. Also, what does `symengine` return.

Comment: I get 2014a from ver symbolic and MuPAD symbolic engine from symengine. It seems my problem is fixed! I reinstalled the entire matlab suite. Now it actually solves and gives me the right answer. I tried reinstalling the toolbox alone but that didn't do anything. At least I found out it was my install from this question and not some commands/settings!  Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I think that you normally what to solve `syms x; xsol = solve(10*x-1, x)` which I think will go through just fine. This is the basic idea of solving equations. So to say finding the root(s) of the equation, which is where the equation is zero. However, your attempt worked just fine for me, matlab 2014b.

Comment: If I do not specify a value it will set the equation to zero and calculate the roots? I'm now finally making progress with my matlab file, everything seems to work!

Comment: @YouKnowNothingJohn This is how one normally view equation solving, so this is set as the default. Actually this is the only logical default value. Also, most numerical methods are developed to find when an expression is zero. If you have a non-zero expression, it is normally possible to arrange the equation to get it in this form.